# How to import pygame, pyperclip?

Tags: python, linux, pygame, debian, pyperclip

I am fairly new to python but am having issues importing certain packages within my code. I try to import `pyperclip` aswell as `pygame`. I've installed them both manually and I've tried importing them using `import pygame` and `import pyperclip` and I get

> "no module named 'pyperclip'"

and the same thing for `pygame`. I've tried opening by putting just `import pygame` and saved it to run it in the interactive shell and I've also just tried typing it into the interactive shell.

I'm running linux mint 17.3 and python 2.7.6
Has anyone else had this issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Za

Comment: what do you mean "manually" ? Didn't you use `pip` or `apt-get` ? You can have many Python version (I use Linux Mint and I have Python 3.4, 2.7, 2.6, 2.4) and maybe you installed in one version and now you use other version.

Comment: I used pip, and I just meant I installed it after the fact, I was using python beforehand and I was able to import random with no issue I have this issue when trying to import these packages

Comment: I had to use `apt-get` to install `pygame` (`python-pygame`) because pygame need some precompilled code in C/C++ and I get error message with `pip` .

Comment: I tried to install `pyperclip` and I got error message. I had to use `sudo` - `sudo pip install pyperclip` - and now I can `import pyperclip`

Comment: For 'pip install pyperclip'  I got "requirement already satisfied and when I 'apt-get install python-pygame' It tells me that it's already in its newest version.

Comment: Pygame isn't too important but pyperclip is directly related to the book I'm in learning python.

Comment: It behaves as you had two Python installed. `pip` installs `pyperclip` in one Python (and it shows that you have `pyperclip` installed) but you run second Python (which has no `pyperclip` installed) and it can't import it. Did you install second Python ? Do you use Anaconda (Python distribution) or PyCharm ?

Comment: I now see that I have multiple versions of python installed I just ran python3.5 to see if anything and the terminal turned into the interactive shell. But still no pyperclip. I'm going to make an attempt on another laptop to import it to see if its an issue with mine

Comment: `pip` is installing for Python2 only. You should have `pip3` to install for Python3. You can even have `pip3.5` (or `pip3.4` if you have Python 3.4). The same way you can have command `python`, `python2`, `python3`, `python3.5`. Try command `which python` to see full path for `python` command or `whereis python` to see full paths for all commands started with `python`. You can write `python` and press key `tab` twice to see all available command started with `python`

Comment: Sooooooo never try to remove a version of python lol i just went apt-get remove python 2.4.3 thinking it would then default to using 3.4 but... Now it looks like a fresh linux installation is needed lol

Comment: Linux use Python in many places so you can remove it. Python 2 and 3 has small differences and system can't use Python 3 in place of Python 2. if you need to use Python 3 then use command `python3` (or `python3.5`). Linux use `shebang` (`#!/use/bin/python3`) in first line of script to inform system which program it has to use to run this script. You can have script name without extension or with extension .php and `shebang` sets to `#!/use/bin/python3` and system will be use Python, not PHP. (it needs also `chmod a+x script` to make it `executable`)

Comment: I found the answer, you were right its because o was trying to run a different version than I had installed the module

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am also new to Python and programming. I tried about 100 things, but what worked for me was typing the following in the command shell:
*pip install pyperclip*

That was it. However, I was using Windows' command module, so. . . you know. But it's worth a shot!

This link might help, too (it has Linux instructions, etc): https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip